# Swing native look and feel vs. AWT style

Tags: java, swing, awt

I've just recently started diving into AWT/Swing as an option to build native UIs and I have made the following observations:

1. using AWT components on Windows I get a classic look (i.e. Windows 2000)
2. using Swing components with native look and feel, I get the flatter Windows 10 appearance.

It's the 2nd visual style I'm aiming for, which leaves me with two questions:

1. Is it possible to somehow make AWT render native components using the newer style?
2. If not, is Swing's native look and feel actually based on OS native widgets or is it some emulation thereof?

Comment: In anticipation of suggestions to use SWT: yes, I'm considering to use that instead, but regardless I'm interested in better understanding this option.

Comment: *"Is it possible to somehow make AWT render native components using the newer style."* No. But why would you want to use AWT components when the Swing API provides more and better ones?

Comment: Because (as stated in the accepted answer) they are not in fact native.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, it is not supported
2. It's an emulation, just a Look and Feel like the others